# How can I change struct name to an integer?

Tags: c++, string, struct

I have been using struct for a while, but there is always a problem with me. See this example:- `

```
#include <iostream>
struct Employee
{
    short id;
    int age;
    double wage;
};

void printInformation(Employee employee)
{
    std::cout << "ID:   " << employee.id << "\n";
    std::cout << "Age:  " << employee.age << "\n";
    std::cout << "Wage: " << employee.wage << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    Employee joe = { 14, 32, 24.15 };
    Employee frank = { 15, 28, 18.27 };
    // Print Joe's information
    printInformation(joe);

    std::cout << "\n";

    // Print Frank's information
    printInformation(frank);

    return 0;
}`
```

This code works completely fine, but when how will I use a string instead of "Joe" And "Frank". I tried but failed.
This is the code on which I am working.

```
 '#include <bits/stdc++.h>
 using namespace std;
 struct People{
   string name;
   int id;
   int age;
   int wage;
   };                
int main(){

string iname;
int iid = 0;
int iage; 
int iwage;     
while(1){
 iid++;
 cout << "ID No." << iid << endl <<"Enter Name";
 std::getline(std::cin,iname);
 cout << "Enter your Age:-";
 cin >> iage;       
  cout << "Enter your Wage :-";
  cin >> iwage; 
  cout << "See your details."<<endl <<"Name"<<iname<< endl<< "ID."<< iid << 
   endl << "Age" << iage << endl<< "Wage" << iwage << endl;
  People a = static_cast<People>(iid);
    People a={iname,iid,iage,iwage};  
    std::cout << "Name:" << a.name << "\n";
 std::cout << "ID:   " << a.id << "\n";
 std::cout << "Age:  " << a.age << "\n";
std::cout << "Wage: " <<  a.wage << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here the user enter its data. I want to save too many data in the form of struct so I used 'a'. According to me it must compute 1.age=(bla..),3.age=(bla..)
Please help me out.

Comment: Are you talking about the variable's name? Post an example of the code you want to work but doesn't.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're looking for something like a std::map

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map

example:

```
std::map<std::string, Employee> employees;
Employee joe = { 14, 32, 24.15 };
employees["joe"] = joe;

printInformation(employees["joe"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also give another variable to each employee, `string name;`, then store the employees in a vector, then in the function loop through the employees until the employee with that name is found:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct Employee{
    string name;
    short id;
    int age;
    double wage;
};

vector<Employee> Employees;
void printInformation(string employee){
    for(int i = 0; i < Employees.size(); i++){
        if(Employees[i].name == employee){
            cout << "Name: " << Employees[i].name << "\n";
            cout << "ID:   " << Employees[i].id << "\n";
            cout << "Age:  " << Employees[i].age << "\n";
            cout << "Wage: " << Employees[i].wage << "\n";
        }
    }
 }

int main(){
    Employee joe = {"joe", 14, 32, 24.15 };
    Employee frank = {"frank", 15, 28, 18.27 };
    Employees.push_back(joe);
    Employees.push_back(frank);
    printInformation("joe");
    printInformation("frank");

    return 0;
}
```

I think it's better than using a map, because you just write `printInformation("joe")`, when when using a map you write `printInformation(employees["joe"])`. You decide.

Comment: My question was not this my question was, How can I make joe and frank to an integer. Here It can be used only two times but here I am using a program of about 16 employees, whose data is to be inputed.